# Run R code on selected object

Tags: ess, r

I am missing (or not aware) of a feature in ESS to run some R code on selected text. When editing a script, like

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1:100,b=rnorm(100))
```

I often want to see `head(df1)` in my terminal. I'd like to be able to move the cursor to `df1` and run an elisp function that sends `head(df1)` to the R terminal.  Can you direct me to how to do that, please? If I can define a few R-functions in Elisp functions and assign them to shortcuts, it would often ease my workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty approach. Depending on what you want there's lots of room for improvement.

```lisp
(defun head-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((target (thing-at-point 'symbol)))
    (ess-send-string (ess-get-process ess-local-process-name)
                     (concat "head(" target ")\n"))))
```

Comment: Thank you, Tyler! Just what I was looking for.